# Spring Boot, DI possible using interface, but not possible in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Spring docs says that currently interface DI is not possible. See here: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/core-concepts-dependency-injection-to-the-rescue.html

I've just started working with Spring boot and I made a simple webapp where I've used DI using interfaces. I can't find the reason on web. Why Spring Boot has this feature while Spring doesn't have!

Please help me in understanding the concept.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Dao Imple.

```
@Repository
public class AbcDaoImpl implements AbcDaoInt{
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Override
    public int selectABC(String user, String password){
        // some db query
    }
```

Dao Interface

```
    @Component
public interface AbcDaoInt{
    int selectABC(String user, String password);    
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class adapter {
    @Autowired
    AbcDaoInt abcDao;

    public Map<String, Object> abc(String user, String password) {

    try{
            int abcId = abcDao.selectABC(user, pwd);
        }
   }
```

Comment: The page you linked to is obsolete, only partially correct, and doesn't define, at all, what it means by "interface injection". You're not saying it either. Spring Boot uses Spring for dependency injection, so the question is moot.

Comment: @RishiPandey could you show us some code. You cannot do interface injection, as you need some concrete implementation. Maybe you are confusing let say @ Autowire Interface interface, where Interface is a some Interface, but the spring will autowire a concrete implementation of it

Comment: @JBNizet what i wanted to point out from linked page that Spring has currently setter and constructor dependency injection. And i know that Spring boot uses Spring for DI. May be i am not understanding the concept but my question is valid.

Comment: @pezetem i am sharing my code. May be you are right that Spring boot is not using interface DI. Please see the code in edit

Comment: @lgor konoplyanko thanks for edit

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between spring and spring-boot regarding DI.
It is possible to use an interface for a field and to inject an implementation into that field.

I do not understand what the linked page means by

> Interface Injection - This is not implemented in Spring currently

it seems to b wrong our outdated.

Comment: @Stefen Thanks for reply. So you mean to say that interface injection is possible in Spring?

Comment: @RishiPandey again, until we have a definition of "interface injection", we can't answer that question. Do you have one?

Comment: we can't define dao interface as bean in Spring mvc, Spring needs impl. class. But in my code(Spring Boot) that i uploaded in edit section: i am using the interfaceDao (abdDao) object. while if i try same in Spring MVC then i will get error at runtime that Spring needs implementation class....?

Answer (score 1):

what exactly are you gonna do with injecting an interface . isn't interfaces are supposed to be implemented by a java class so whenever you are injecting a interface that means some class implementing the interface should be injected.

this is how you should do it, you have to  enable component scan on the package where these classes are present then enable annotaions in order to use annotations.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="" /> 
<mvc:annotation-driven> 


public interface singleInterface{
    void someMethod();
}

@Component(value="b")
class B implements singleInterface{
    public void someMethod(){
    System.out.println(“from b class”);
    }
}

@Component(value=“a”)
class A implements singleInterface{
    public void someMethod(){
    System.out.println(“from A class”);
    }
}

//injecting

 @Autowire
 @Qualifier("b") 
 singleInterface bInterface;

 bInterface.someMethod();//print from b class. 

 @Autowire
 @Qualifier("a") 
 singleInterface aInterface;

 aInterface.someMethod();//print from a class.
```

this works on `spring boot` and on `spring mvc` you dont have to enable `component scan` in spring boot.

Comment: My code is working as well. My question was why Spring Boot allows interface DI. while docs says Spring does not allows interface DI.

Comment: the above post is coded with spring , why do you say thats not allowed?

Comment: This is exactly that i wanna know. 
we can't define dao interface as bean in Spring mvc, Spring needs impl. class. But the code i posted in edit section of my question is using Spring Boot, where we don't need to specify xml config. and beans